# Program execution in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, process, operating-system

I would like to know exactly what sequence of events are followed when a program (Say a C code image) is executed in Linux based OS.

Somethings I know beforehand:

a) The memory map of the executable image of program is made using structure mm_struct. This structure contains vm_area_structs that points to various sections of a program, say code, bss, data etc. What I don't know is when this memory map made? Is it made when the program is made "runnable" by OS? If not, then exactly when?

b) http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html mentions that **As only the very start of the image is physically pulled into memory it will soon access an area of virtual memory that is not yet in physical memory.** Now I understand that only pages in main memory are used by processors; and that these pages may contain either data or code. Since the program is bought into execution, it's first code instructions must also be in memory at this point of time, in some physical page. Also, a page table corresponding to this process must be there in main memory. When exactly is this page table created and when was the first code instruction page loaded in main memory?

Comment: " Is it made when the program is made "runnable" by OS?". Yes. The runtime loader (`ldd` in Linux) requests the mappings based on ELF info (assuming ELF) in the executables and requests the appropriate mappings from the kernel.